# Batch Size Problem with MapR Streams Kafka API

Tags: java, kafka-consumer-api, mapr, batchsize

Hello i am using Kafka MapRStream to recieve Events from a Mapr Streams Topic.

I am trying to **increase** the batch size of my consumer but i am not getting more than **30** messages in **one batch**!

A single event is about 5000 bytes in size. If the event is smaller I get more in one batch.

Here is my configuration of the **Consumer:**

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "batchSize");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "true");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MIN_BYTES_CONFIG, 50000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.RECEIVE_BUFFER_CONFIG, 26214400);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, 100 * 1024 * 1024);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 1000);


        Consumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(TOPIC));
        long totalCount = 0;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long countTimesNoMessages = 0;

        while (countTimesNoMessages < 10) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(1000);
            totalCount += records.count();
            System.out.println(records.count());
            if (records.count() == 0) {
                countTimesNoMessages++;
            }
        }

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println((end - start) + " for " + totalCount + " messages");
    }
```

Comment: how many messages are coming in topic per second?

Comment: The topic is full of messages, it comes about 500 per second and already contains 1 million

Answer (score 0):

These are the possible configuration points.

https://mapr.com/docs/61/MapR_Streams/configuration-parameters.html

notice that `fetch.max.bytes` is the total max and `sum(max.partition.fetch.bytes)` over all partitions cannot go over fetch.max.bytes.

It is normal to adjust `max.partition.fetch.bytes` so more than 64Kb (default) are poll from each partition and also will adjust `fetch.max.bytes` so that it allows `max.partition.fetch.bytes` to work properly.

You shouldn't probably set the batch size too large. Once the frequency of requests to poll the stream drops below several hundred per second or so, you are very unlikely to get additional improvements in performance and are much more likely to have problems with hotspots or large amounts of redone work in the event of failed threads.

Comment: by default the fetch.max.bytes is already (50*1024*1024) 50mb

Comment: And then what is the partition limit?

Comment: now i set it to 3mb but nothing changed. I have 12 partitions with one consumer.

Comment: Please replicate this with a small demonstration program and post the code publicly. Without the details of the code, it isn't possible to debug this.